# Symfony2 twig edit form not calling the controller

Tags: symfony, twig

i did edit function for notification and override the default form widget using my html fields at this time not call the controller but i did create function it has working properly

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<h1>Notification edit</h1>
<form name="custom_edit" action="{{ path('notification_edit', { 'id' :        notification.id }) }}"  method="POST"  {{ form_enctype(edit_form) }}> 
<input type="text" name="notification[type]" required /> 
<input type="submit" value="Edit" />
  </form> 
  {% endblock %}
```

here is my controller code

```
/**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Notification entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="notification_edit")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Notification $notification)
    {

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($notification);
        $editForm = $this->createForm('LencoBundle\Form\NotificationType', $notification);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {


            $type = $editForm['type']->getData();

            print_r($type);exit;
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($notification);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('notification_edit', array('id' => $notification->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('notification/edit.html.twig', array(
            'notification' => $notification,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

but  {{ form_widget(edit_form) }} using this widget form call the controller works

Comment: You shouldn't write the html for your input fields manually, let symfony do that for you.

Comment: how to override default widget form design in twig, becoz i want to use my customize design front end kindly suggest me any reference or links

Comment: You can use form themes: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#forms-and-doctrine which is pretty helpful.

If you've created the Form using your Entity Class, which seems to be the case according to your code, you don't need to edit the form widget.

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($notification);
$em->flush();

return $this->redirectToRoute(//Your route to success);
}
```

Comment: @Bandana Answer should be more descriptive than just the link beacuse the link can be dead anytime

Answer (score 0):

From how you have written you code, you are passing an id field to the controller and expecting it to use an object (of type Notification).

This can be done if you use the [param converter annotation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html)

You controller annotation should look something like;

```
/**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Notification entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="notification_edit")
     * @ParamConverter("notification", class="AppBundle:Notification")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practise is to use the form_widget, because it takes the name of your form (`LencoBundle\Form\NotificationType`) and use it for the name of the inputs, in this case I imagine your form `getName()` function returns "notification" and it has a field named "type", otherwise it won't work. (Maybe a typo or the camelized name)

You should use `form_widget` directly, and I advice you to use `form_rest` to add the [CSRF protection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/csrf_in_login_form.html) to your forms automaticaly. You can use it for a form field instead the full field, either using it by itself or the combination of `form_label` + `form_widget` + `form_errors`.

If you need to modify the template of how is renderer you can do it anyway with Twig, using [form themes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes).

Comment: If I am using form_widget(edit_form) its showing all database fields. But I need to show some fields only. So I wrote like this but it cannot call controller. If I use form_widget it can call controller.

Comment: You can use form_widget for a single field of the field: `form_widget(form.type)`